Jenkins agent pods should keep running if the pipeline fails
I have deployed jenkins using the official helm charts on EKS cluster.
If my pipeline fails on jenkins, I want my agent pod to keep running for certain amount of time. Also the idle agent pod should not be used to execute pipeline or new run of the pipeline.
I tried setting the pod retention
Pod retention, but that didn't work.
Please do let me know if we can configure that in jenkins?
Thanks in advance

I don't think there is any option in Jenkins to keep fail job to run for specific amount of time.
But since Jenkins have try/catch error handling you can utilize that and just run sleep xxx command when something is failing.
Sample code:
try {
  sh """
    cat /home/user1/some_file.txt
  """
}
catch (Exception e) {
  sh """
    sleep 600
  """
}

